# Weird issue with numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

## Information

`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

## Issue

```
1000000000000 === 999999999999.999999  // Gives output true
1000000000000 === 999999999999.99999   // Gives output true
1000000000000 === 999999999999.9999    // Gives output false
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: In short: never expect any particular floating point number to be exactly equal to any other number. Yes, you can probably figure out what exactly is happening here if you dig into it, but why bother when you're violating a fundamental principle of working with inaccurate floats to begin with?

Comment: I can understand why floating point operations (like addition) fails. But why should something like equality fail? `(0.1 + 0.2) === 0.3 // gives false` makes sense. But not this.

Comment: If a value simply cannot be expressed precisely in float, it snaps to another value close by that *can* be expressed. Here the first two numbers round up to `1000000000000`, simply by the mere fact of trying to express them.

Comment: When the decimal numerals are converted to a JavaScript `Number`, the result is the number represented by the decimal numeral rounded to the nearest value representable in floating-point. For “999999999999.99999” and “999999999999.99999”, the nearest representable value is 1000000000000. So `999999999999.99999` in source code becomes 1000000000000, and then comparison for equality is comparing 1000000000000 to 1000000000000, so it returns true. In the case of “999999999999.9999”, the nearest value is 999999999999.9998779296875, so the comparison returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Because floats have low precision.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point

Comment: A 64-bit floating-point number has more precision than a 32-bit integer. It is not the degree of precision *per se* that causes floating-point rounding issues but rather than nature of how they behave compared to what people expect.

Comment: well a decimal is base 10 while computers work in base 2 perhaps i formulated myself incorrectly when I used the term precision.